# PHP get twitter username from site visitor

Tags: php, twitter

I'm not quite sure if this is possible, but I am looking for a way to get the twitter username of a person visiting a website. Does anyone know if there is a way to do this, or if I always need a user to confirm that I am seeing this data?

Preferably I'm looking for a PHP library that I can do this with.

Comment: https://dev.twitter.com/resources/twitter-libraries

Comment: You need to request that information from the user you can't just get it from them visiting your site, see the docs https://dev.twitter.com/

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not possible. Think of the security vulnerabilities: if any website could access your Twitter account information without your permission, then you essentially have no privacy.

You need to use OAuth to first ask the user to sign in. Then, you will have limited access to that user's account information.

[Here](https://dev.twitter.com/resources/twitter-libraries#php) is a list of PHP libraries to help you do this.

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense.

Comment: You're welcome, best of luck!